# Angular $mdDialog - displaying in same window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mddialog

I have been messing with the $mdDialog and have copied code verbatim from [Angular.org Demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog).  When executing, the result displays in the current window and not an overlayed dialog like the example.  The result is the same for each scenario (alert, confirm, prompt, custom, and tab) and has been run in both Chrome and Firefox.

The following [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQNNXB) replicates the issue.  The HTML is below with the CSS and JS in CodePen.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>MVA Intro to Angular</title>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/fundraising-section.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<!--<body ng-app="mainApp">-->
<body ng-controller="testDialogCtrl">

<div ng-controller="testDialogCtrl">
    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAlert($event)">
        Alert Dialog
    </md-button>
    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showConfirm($event)">
        Confirm Dialog
    </md-button>
    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showPrompt($event)">
        Prompt Dialog
    </md-button>
    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAdvanced($event)">
        Custom Dialog
    </md-button>
    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showTabDialog($event)">
        Tab Dialog
    </md-button>
</div>

<!-- /.container -->
<!--<script type="text/ng-template" id="uiSelect" src="app/shared/uiSelect.html"></script>-->
<script src="Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<!--<script src="app/main.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("angular object", angular);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some code? (a CodePen or JSFiddle?)

Comment: From the hyperlink in the post, there's a CodePen link to the right of the "Basic Usage" header.

Comment: Yeah, the code from the doc obviously works. But yours doesn't, so if you want us to help you, we need to see how you're using this directive in your code :)

Comment: Add above in main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.  After learning a bit more about CodePen and adding resources, the the CSS resource was needed in the project.

https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.1/angular-material.css

Comment: Excellent, it's always better when you fix your issues by yourself :-)